# RadFlowDocument adjust table cell width

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I'm using Telerik 2016 Q1, Visual Studio 2013, visual basic and MVC.  I'm attempting to generate a pdf using the RadFlowDocument.  My pdf contains a table which includes a row for an employee's name, followed by a row for each item assigned to that employee.  This information repeats, so that there will be a row with a name, then 4 rows with items, then another name, followed by more items.

The row for the employee name should span the width of the table, and have a different background color, to make it stand out.  I have tried adjusting the `tableCell.PrefferedWidth`, however this does not seem to have any effect on the output.

Here is the loop that creates the table:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To numberOfSubordinates - 1
        Dim currentSubordinate As Subordinate = neededInformation.Subordinates(i)

        Dim employeeNameRow As TableRow = itemTable.Rows.AddTableRow()
        Dim employeeNameCell As TableCell = employeeNameRow.Cells.AddTableCell()
        employeeNameCell.Blocks.AddParagraph.Inlines.AddRun(currentSubordinate.Name)
        employeeNameCell.Shading.BackgroundColor = cellBackground
        employeeNameCell.PreferredWidth = New TableWidthUnit(150)

        For j As Integer = 0 To currentSubordinate.Items.Count - 1
            Dim row As TableRow = itemTable.Rows.AddTableRow()

            Dim itemTypeCell As TableCell = row.Cells.AddTableCell()
            Dim manufacturerCell As TableCell = row.Cells.AddTableCell()
            Dim modelCell As TableCell = row.Cells.AddTableCell()
            Dim locationCell As TableCell = row.Cells.AddTableCell()
            Dim serialNumberCell As TableCell = row.Cells.AddTableCell()
            Dim tagNumberCell As TableCell = row.Cells.AddTableCell()

            Dim currentItem = currentSubordinate.Items(j)

            itemTypeCell.Blocks.AddParagraph().Inlines.AddRun(currentItem.ItemType)
            manufacturerCell.Blocks.AddParagraph.Inlines.AddRun(currentItem.Manufacturer)
            modelCell.Blocks.AddParagraph.Inlines.AddRun(currentItem.Model)
            locationCell.Blocks.AddParagraph.Inlines.AddRun(currentItem.Location)
            serialNumberCell.Blocks.AddParagraph.Inlines.AddRun(currentItem.SerialNumber)
            tagNumberCell.Blocks.AddParagraph.Inlines.AddRun(currentItem.MCSCTagNumber)
        Next

    Next
```

How do I extend the employee name rows so that the name doesn't wrap, and the background color extends the length of the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the `cell.ColumnSpan`.  In the case of this table, which has 6 columns, in order to have a row that spans the entire table the adjustment should read:  `employeeNameCell.ColumnSpan = 6`.